# Assigning 'groupings' for readability in C

Tags: c

Is it possible to do something like the following in C to help with how I would read the code?

Instead of writing:

```
struct OpType *OpTypePtr;
```

To write it something like:

```
(struct OpType) *OpTypePtr;
```

Is there some way to do this in C?

Comment: That does not improve readability. Of course that's a subjective statement. But almost nobody writes code like that and keeping to common practices is usually a good thing when writing code that will be seen by more than the author.

Comment: The problem exists in your head. Instead of adapting the code to how your mind works, alter your mind to learn to read the code. Otherwise you will never be able to read/write code with other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you really want, you can create a user-defined type using `typedef`.

Something like

```
typedef struct OpType optype_t;
optype_t *OpTypePtr;
```